# How To Stop actionPoller After Set Duration?

Tags: visualforce, ajax, actionpoller

Can we stop the [`<apex:actionPoller>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionPoller.htm) from executing after a set duration?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can tweak the example from the docs just slightly to check an `isEnabled` property.

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class Demo
{
    final Long start = Datetime.now().getTime();
    public Boolean getIsEnabled() { return Datetime.now().getTime() - start < 60 * 1000; }

    Integer count = 0;
    public Integer getCount() { return count; }
    public PageReference incrementCounter() {
        count++;
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Page**

```
<apex:page controller="Demo">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:outputText value="Watch this counter: {!count}" id="counter"/>
        <apex:actionPoller action="{!incrementCounter}" reRender="counter" interval="5" enabled="{!isEnabled}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```